# "Not only will we ..." or "We will not only ..."?

Tags: word-order

Is it possible that both of the following sentences are correct? Or is only the second one correct?

> **Not only will we** hear more noise during the day and night, but we will also lose our special old park.
>
> **We will not only** hear more noise during the day and at night, but we will also lose our special old park.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, I think both are possible. I also think the first one sounds more formal.

Comment: What @Fantasier said. But also note that the further you remove ***only*** from its referent (***hear***, in this case), the more scope there is for totally different senses to creep in. *"Not only will we hear more noise, so will people living miles away."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Not only" can be moved to the beginning of the clause **for emphasis**. It is then followed by auxiliary verb+subject. If there is no other auxiliary, "do"is used. "But" can be left out in this case. Examples:

1. Not only has she been late three times, she has also done no work.
2. Not only do they need clothing, but they are also short of water.

Your second sentence, as mentioned by Fantasier, is correct.

Comment: +1 particularly for pointing out that ***but*** can often be left out. Personally, I find it a bit "awkward/unnatural" in OP's example #1.

Comment: You're right. I agree with you. It seems a bit awkward.